# Determine whether a function on the even integers is injective and surjective

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Let $E$ be the set of even integers. Define $f:E \rightarrow \{0, 1, 2, 3, 4\}$ by $f(n) = n \mod 5$.

a) Determine whether $f$ is one-to-one (injective).

b) Determine whether $f$ is onto (surjective).

Comment: Okay.  Done.  How are you going?  What do "one-to-one" and "onto" mean to you?  (Always begin your solution with the definitions.)

Comment: $f(0) = 0$ but $f(5) = 0$.

Comment: This sort of question is trying to see if you understand the definitions.  If you cannot answer it, look up the definitions and read them carefully.  What does injective mean?  What does surjective mean?  Read them again.  Try some small $n$ and see what happens.  Try *something*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $m=4 \in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(4)=4 mod 5$
And $n=9 \in \mathbb{N}$ then $f(9)=4 mod 5$
Since $n, m \in \mathbb{N} $such that $m\not=n$
And $f(n) =f(m) $the function don't is one to one.
And now you try if f is onto using the definition, like
$F:=A \rightarrow B$ said onto if for every $ y\in B
\exists x \in A : F(x) =y$

Comment: MathJax hint:  for common functions, precede them with a backslash and you will get the right font and spacing.  We would more commonly write $f(4) \equiv 4 \pmod 5$.  You can right click on any MathJax and pick Show Math As ->TeX Commands to see how it was done.  I used \pmod to get the right font for mod and the parentheses around it.  We would also use \equiv to get three lines for equivalent instead of =